# Regex within Redis Set

Tags: regex, redis, set

I have recently been started to play around with Redis (and am extremely pleased with all the functions it has to offer).

In particular, I was looking for a way to find all elements within a set for which a regex matches.

For example:

```
>>smember WORDS
  1) "person"
  2) "saint church"
  3) "saint house"
```

If I wanted to return only the elements where "saint" is present, how would I do so?

I have tried to use sscan as follows:

```
sscan WORDS match *saint*
```

for which I get an error. 
My understanding was that sscan can return "array of elements is a list of Set members"

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Regardless the error, note that `SCAN` et al do not deliver full blown PCRE but rather a less ambitious glob-like pattern matching

Comment: thank you! that is helpful to know.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have no more than 1000 elements matching you can use

```
sscan  WORDS 0 match *saint* count 1000
```

If you want know the exact numbers of the elements in the set you can use **SMEMBERS** command.

If you want know the exact numbers of the elements in the set that MATCH with your regex, in a single command no a specific command.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a ZERO as the *cursor* parameter for the [SCAN](http://redis.io/commands/scan):

```
sscan WORDS 0 match *saint*
```

Comment: thanks so much, I get what I believe is the index number. Is there a particular way to double check to see the exact element / elements of the set?